# Calculating Percentage within a MYSQL Group

Tags: mysql

My query calculates the total numbers of calls within SLA by priority. However now I need to work out the percentage of calls that were within SLA by priority within the same statement

However I am unsure how to do this within my current statement

```
`SELECT
 SUM(o.withinfix) 'Total'
 ,o.priority 'priority'
 FROM opencall o
 WHERE LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex),4) = "2013"
 AND o.fk_company_id = "abc"
 GROUP BY o.priority'
```

Can anyone help, I using MYSQL 5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT SUM(o.withinfix) 'Total',
        SUM(o.withinfix) / (select SUM(withinfix) from opencall) * 100 as perc
        o.priority 'priority'
 FROM opencall o
 WHERE LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex),4) = "2013"
 AND o.fk_company_id = "abc"
 GROUP BY o.priority
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just with subselect of total:

```
SELECT SUM(o.withinfix) 'Total' ,o.priority 'priority',
    (SELECT SUM(withinfix) FROM opencall AS o2 GROUP BY o2.priority) AS sum_total
FROM opencall o
WHERE LEFT(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.logdatex),4) = "2013"
AND o.fk_company_id = "abc" GROUP BY o.priority'
```

And after query manually calculate percantage.